# Custom Property Binding member of view model with type List<Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm trying to submit a collection of expressions from my view to my controller.  The view model is something like this:

```
public class Model<T> {

  public List<Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>> Expressions {get; set;};

}
```

Ideally, I'd like to markup the Expressions member with an attribute which indicates the model binder to use to deserialize each of the Expressions in the collection.

I assume the challenging part is deserializing the expression, however for the moment I'm stumped just figuring out how to create an attribute such as the one described above.  Several answers here and on the internet describe doing this, however, they seem to use some version of MS MVC other than the one I'm on.  They all seem to assume that the IModelBinder defines a `BindProperty` method which takes as one of its arguments a `PropertyDescriptor` object.  No such members seem to be available in the version I'm on.

I believe that the default model binder is properly handling the fact that the data is bound to a collection because the resulting collection has the correct number of entries, but they are all null.  This is what leads me to believe that the underlying issue is that the default binder does not know what to do with something that looks like `x => x.MyMember`, which I think I can figure out provided I can attach a custom property binder attribute of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by way of creating a custom type converter for a wrapper around the lambda expression.  Within the type converter, I use System.Linq.Dynamic, available on NuGet to parse the lambda expression and map it back to the view model.  Relevant snippets below:

```
public class Model<T> {

  public List<Expression<Func<T, dynamic>>> Expressions {get; set;};

}
```

Becomes:

```
public class Model<T> {

  public List<ColumnSelector<T>> Expressions {get; set;};

}
```

I wrapped the problematic Expression in a simple wrapper class like so:

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(ExpressionDescriptorProvider))]
public class ColumnSelector <T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> Expression { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Expression.ToString();
    }
}
```

Once the `TypeDescriptorProvider` and `ExpressionDescriptorProvider` are implemented, model binding just works like you'd expect it to.

```
public class ExpressionConverter<T> : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        //i'm essentially desserializing from a string, so we return true in that case
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var stringValue = value as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        {
            string[] parts = stringValue.Split(new[] {" => "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            string param = parts[0];
            string expression = parts[1];

            bool nullable = false;
            if (expression.Contains("Convert"))
            {
                //any exceptions originating in this method may be indicative that more
                //conditions need to be tested and handled here
                expression = expression.Replace("Convert(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty);
                nullable = true;
            }

            ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), param);

            //this line is from the above mentioned NuGetPackage
            LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expression);

            Expression body = lambdaExpression.Body;

            if (nullable)
            {
                //this is a special case for handling members which are nullable,
                //there may be other special cases which we need to address
                body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(Object));
            }

            Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> lamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(body, p);

            ColumnSelector<T> obj = new ColumnSelector<T> { Expression = lamda };

            return obj;
        }

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to convert object {0} to ColumnSelector<T>.", value));
    }
}
```

And then we need some boilerplate to get it all wired up:

```
public class ExpressionDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private readonly Type _objectType;

    public ExpressionDescriptor(Type objectType)
    {
        this._objectType = objectType;
    }

    public override TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        var genericArg = _objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var converterType = typeof(ExpressionConverter<>).MakeGenericType(genericArg);
        return (TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(converterType);
    }
}

public class ExpressionDescriptorProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return new ExpressionDescriptor(objectType);
    }
}
```